# Is there any way to get around having everyone in the world speak the same language?

Tags: technique, characters, plot, planning, tropes

You see this a lot in fantasy fiction, where everyone on the planet (and sometimes beyond) speaks the same language, even though it makes absolutely no logical sense for them to have any knowledge of each other's languages.

Of course, if you try to avoid this, then you run into the problem of characters not being able to communicate.

The first option is obviously illogical and to me, stupid, but at the same time it makes practical sense. And looking at the fantasy genre, it seems everyone just goes with that and ignores the non-sensicalness of it.

But is there anyway to work around this? Has anyone come up with a way to avoid this irritating trope?

Comment: There are many things in fantasy that are nonsensical. Last week I mentioned it would be nonsensical to have a hospital patient who had zero nurses. The counterargument is that it makes the story more efficiently (better) told. It is nonsensical that every decision a character makes is towards a single goal of resolving their moral dilemma. That's not true to life. But it is true to story. I had feedback IRL that my characters should not eat meat because I will lose readers. Nonsensical, but pragmatic. But also an opportunity. (The villains can eat meat, lol :-) )

Comment: Forget about all of the characters speaking the same language. Consider that all of the characters speak *the reader's language*. On a remote planet orbiting a star in a distant part of a galaxy far, far, far away, just what is the probability of *that?* :-)

Comment: @DPT Are you saying your villains aren't characters...? :)

Comment: @lXBlackWolfXl You may be interested in [Scenes with different languages spoken after translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/21877/2533)

Comment: Note that this isn't something that's restricted to fantasy fiction. You have basically the same issue with real-world novels where people travel between countries. Generally speaking, though, authors don't bother with translation issues unless it's a plot point or intended as "local color" (e.g. vacationers to Brazil's Carnaval tend not to struggle with Portuguese, and characters visiting Paris aren't flummoxed by French. If your car breaks down in Mongolia, there's never an issue communicating with the local mechanic or hotel owner -- unless the author wants there to be.)

Comment: I think this one may be more suited for WorldBuilding.SE than here.

Comment: If you want to make a multi-language world, can't you just model your written world off of the real-world? You can go into as much detail as you like on coping with multiple languages and characters that can't communicate with each other. But don't let it get in the way of the story -- which is why many writers ignore it or explain it away through "magic" (universal translaters, babelfish, etc)

Comment: Try to look at how other fantasy writers do this. The first big names that come to mind are J.R.R. Tolkien and G.R.R. Martin

Comment: One language per planet doesn't seem that unrealistic to me. Already today, most users of the internet understand english. I would predict that further globalization would lead to more and more people speaking the same universal language

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Worldbuilding.SE

Comment: You don't actually see that all 10 billion inhabitants speak the same language, as much as you see the 20 story characters from different areas (can) all speak the same language. Which makes sense - given a choice, they're more likely to meet, have conversations with, buy from, and generally go on adventures with, people they understand rather than people they can't communicate with. Story anthropic-principle style.

Comment: Unless the story is about the difficulties in communication and perhaps culture, I would not add additional languages. Adding the groovestutter of a translator will not help advance the story.

Comment: @lucidbrot And on a smaller scale, this is what Kreole languages start as, kind of. You have French guys and English guys - the French don't speak English, the English don't speak French, but both can reasonably well communicate using the simple French-English Kreole (the same language developing to a full-blown national language over time gets you bonus points :P). Not to mention that language transitions were often smooth - if you just kept walking in one direction, you could slowly adapt to the differences and keep understanding well enough (there are many exceptions, of course).

Comment: "And looking at the fantasy genre, it seems everyone just goes with that and ignores the non-sensicalness of it." Really?  One of the most prominent examples I can think of, *The Wheel of Time,* goes nonsensical in the exact opposite direction.  There's a Common Tongue (English), and then there's the Old Tongue, which appears to have no linguistic connection whatsoever to English, even though it was spoken in the same lands.  And when invaders from across the sea show up, they speak the Old Tongue and it's perfectly understandable by locals who understand the Old Tongue.

Comment: This is a terrific question.  For Worldbuilding.

Answer (score 25):

There are several ways to have more than one language in your world. Here are some ideas:

- Your characters might be conversant in more than one language. If your characters are high-born or a hereditary merchants, it makes perfect sense for foreign languages to be part of their education. You can even mention they have an accent, or have trouble understanding expressions.
- There might be a [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) - a language that people learn as a second language for the explicit purpose of communicating with other people whose language they don't share.
- People might actually not understand each other, communicate through hand gestures, seek a translator, etc.
- There is the option of magic/translator microbes/babel fish - a fantasy tool fitted to the setting, that just lets people understand each other. But that, in my opinion, is the least interesting solution. (Not that it's always bad. Sometimes it's boring but practical - handwaves the problem, and lets you get on with telling the story.)

Some books in the fantasy genre make use of these tools. Look, for example, at the "Lord of the Rings": "Common Speech" (a.k.a English) is a language all characters are at least conversant in, it is the lingua franca of western Middle Earth, as well as the MCs' mother tongue. However, the hobbits have their unique dialect of "Common", with some unique words. Frodo, the MC, knows enough Quenya (one of the languages of the elves) for a polite greeting, but not much more than that (basically "please" and "thank you"). While elven nobility are fluent in Quenya, Sindarin and Common, we also encounter elves who do not speak Common, and Legolas, an elf, serves as translator.The Rohirrim (a human nation) have their own language, which the hobbits recognise as being somewhat related to where their unique words come from. When the Rohirrim choose not to address visitors in Common, it is considered lack of courtesy, but they certainly talk and sing in their own language among themselves (Aragorn is the one to translate this time). There's also the language of the Dwarves, which they keep secret from strangers so we only get glimpses of it in place names, Dark Speech (with multiple dialects), whatever languages the Southorns and Easterlings speak (we know nothing of those save that they are not the Common), and so on.

Comment: "Magic/techno translation" can be used without it being wholly boring IMO if rather than fully translating it simply gives you the gist of what the person is trying to get across (eg, for non humanoid species it could indicate tone and body language for the unfamiliar).

Comment: My unnecessary attention to useless details prompts me to tell you the Common Language in LotR is actually named Westron. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: Babel fish was what occurred to me

Comment: IIRC, Arthur C. Clarke's Rama books had one set of aliens capture Nicole des Jardins' child and genetically engineer him to be able to better read their colour-pattern based communications when he grew up. Vernor Vinge's Deepness in the Sky trilogy has a skilled translator drugged to the point of slavis hyper-focus until she could translate intercepted alien communications. Not really planet-scale answers there though. Another common handwaving-away-language-concerns trope is telepathy, where the alien communication appears directly in the character's mind.

Answer (score 16):

You can work around the language barrier the same way we do in real life: **have someone act as a translator**. There are three ways of introducing such a character:

- **Option 1:** The moment the need for a translator arises, one of your characters randomly sticks his hand up and goes, "Oh, I speak language X!" Don't do this, except for comedy value (see: *Airplane!*). It's a lazy deus ex machina.
- **Option 2:** The characters know they'll need someone who speaks language X, and seek them out in advance. This may mean having to create a new character just to fulfil the "translator" role, though.
- **Option 3:** The people who speak language X bring a translator along with them when they meet the protgaonists. This is my personal preference: it's a much less jarring handwave than Option 1.

None of these options are perfect, but of course, there's a reason many fantasy works use the "everyone speaks the same language" handwave: sheer convenience. It annoys me too, though, so kudos to you for breaking the mould.

Comment: Upvoted. Option 3 creates opportunity to reveal thought processes among the group while still presenting them as a united voice. You can show a cultural conflict/hesitation/debate without stating it explicitly…. Option 2 puts a new character in the room who can show an everyman reaction to negotiations that would never be displayed by the negotiators.

Comment: Option 4: The Stargate route; start out with option 2, but somewhere along the way in the story completely forget that a translator was necessary at all. Or Option 5: The Startrek route; there's a techno-magical device that automatically live translates for them (which will be obvious that it was occurring by lip movements not matching the sound), but then sometimes you have an episode where the protagonists are posing as a species who speak a language the protagonists don't and the aliens are none the wiser.

Comment: For the record, Option 1 might not be a deus ex machina if you set it up right -- mention that this person is a language nerd when she's not studying swordplay, or that she's been a mercenary in dozens of different countries (and scale her language knowledge appropriately). The key, as with anything like that, is to not pull it out of nowhere, and reference the setup when you do -- e.g. "I've worked in most countries. Seen a lot of things." -> "Yeah, I speak X. Worked there for... 'bout 7 years. Not fluent, but probably good enough."

Comment: Another option: While there are different languages, there's one dominant language that is understood by many people throughout the part of the world relevant for the story. At Roman times, you could have expected to communicate in Latin everywhere in the Roman empire, and probably also in many of the neighbouring provinces. In today's world, many people speak English all around the world.

Comment: Careful [who you call a "Lazy Deus"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPOT9ZVW0hg)

Comment: @Shufflepants There's also Plot Choice 5A, wherein there exists a universal translator, but it breaks down (or fails to function in the first place) precisely when the protagonists encounter a particularly hostile group. See the Star Trek *Voyager* encounter with Species 8472, or the "Think Tank", for examples of this.

Answer (score 4):

It may or may not be true that every [crisis in the real world is an opportunity](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/comment/edmundconway/5401596/Every-crisis-is-an-opportunity-this-time-its-the-chance-to-spend-less.html), but it *is* true that every writing challenge is a writing opportunity.  The challenge of multiple language isn't an obstacle to overcome, it's a chance to show things about the world your characters live in, the mindset of your world's difficult cultures, the relationship between societies, the developing relationships between characters who speak different languages, and so forth.

Of course, doing that well would take a lot of work.  If you don't want to put that effort in --no judgement --the best choice is probably to just do what everyone else does and ignore the implausibility of it.  Like other standard choices, it becomes invisible that way.  Any other way of addressing it will probably just call unwanted attention to it.

It's worth noting however, that quite a large percentage of the real world population is in fact fluent in multiple languages.  If you're willing to foreground this aspect of your worldbuilding, the possibilities are endless.  Which language is high status?  Which is low status?  Who knows multiple languages, and who doesn't?  Who secretly understands a language she pretends not to?  Who secretly doesn't understand a language as well as he pretends?  What happens when you absolutely have to communicate with someone whose language is utterly alien?  The storytelling possibilities are wide open. (Samuel Delany even developed an entire, [critically acclaimed novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel-17) around this very issue --a linguist was his hero.)

Answer (score 4):

You really misunderstand how fiction works.

In most novels and short stories the characters never visit the toilet. Does that mean that Frodo, Macbeth, or Odysseus never defecated? No. It just means that everyone knows that people have to move their bowels, and that since it is irrelevant to the story it is not mentioned. Just like breathing, wearing clothes, and everything else that people do on a regular basis and take for granted.

Now everyone knows from personal experience that people speak different languages and that you have to learn foreign languages to communicate internationally. It is such a common and therefore banal fact of everyday life, that you don't have to mention it in fiction for readers to understand that it is going on when people from different countries interact.

---

That said, languages do play a role in many works of fantasy and science fiction, when they are relevant to the storyline. A recent example is the movie *Arrival* in which the attempt to communicate with aliens is the driving "antagonistic" force of the plot and the heroine is a linguist.

Translation devices, such as *Star Trek's* "universal translator", are a common gadget in SF, but there are quite a few fantasy novels in which language learning or translators play some role, as well. And if they don't, just think of how often you heard of interpreters in history class in school – probably never, although they are just as much a part of trade and politics, both in the real world and in fantasy novels, as aides, chauffeurs, or speechwriters (of which you don't hear much in reality or fantasy, either).

Comment: I tend to disagree. I'd say that if your story has people from different countries/cultures interact with one another, then it should incorporate a mention of their use of a common language, since that is a major factor in their ability to communicate at all.

You gave defecation as your analogy, but I'd say that a more suitable analogy would be physical appearance. Having the writer not mention the language in a multicultural interaction (equivalently not have the characters notice it) is as significant an omittance as not mentioning their physical appearance at all.

Comment: @yoniLavi An yet many novels do not mention the physical appearance of the main characters! (Or do you know what Lewis Caroll's *Alice* looks like?)

Comment: thanks @flinder that's an interesting example, but is it actually "many" novels? And for what it's worth, this is what Alice looks like, as in the drawings that Caroll commissioned from Tenniel and were included in the original print - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alice_par_John_Tenniel_04.png

Comment: Your first sentence is too harsh. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: "A recent example is the movie Arrival in which the attempt to communicate with aliens is the driving "antagonistic" force of the plot" Actually, other humans are the antagonists.

Answer (score 3):

#### Farscape Translator Microbes.

In the SyFy series Farscape, [Translator Microbes](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Translator_microbe) infected everybody, including the human thrust into this alien universe. In the pilot episode, John Crichton pops out of a wormhole and ends up on an alien ship. Everybody on it is talking gibberish. He clearly does not understand them, then a little floor robot thing injects him with something. A few minutes later their speech is interspersed with English and then they all seem to be talking English.

Your exact point is made by Crichton about this; they explain somehow he was raised without the translator microbes so they ordered the robot to inject him. Everybody speaks their own languages, but it is automatically translated.

Near the end of the series (1993) astronaut John Crichton finally makes his way back to Earth, and can understand every language on Earth.

Comment: They could also put [fishes into their ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Babel_fish).

Comment: Now that explains one of the silly things that always bothered me about _Star_Wars_!

Answer (score 3):

**Write what people intended to say, not the sounds of the words.**

We don't write character accents phonetically (hopefully). We don't add every "um…" and pause that's used in normal speech. Instead we write what characters *meant*, not the individual phonems coming out of their mouths.

By extension, we don't need to hear that lizardmen lisp the letter S, and that werewolves have trouble with P and M because fangs don't allow their lips to close. Unless there is some specific comedy of errors because of a mispronunciation, or the accent makes them the butt of a joke, it's better to just write what they meant.

Speaking a different language is a bit of a leap, but really it is the same idea. It doesn't matter which language they use at any moment, they may be bilingual or working among others in a common language of borrowed words, what matters is what they intended to communicate. So just write what they meant.

When the POV is third-person limited, your MC will either understand what was said or not, as the plot dictates. The longer she hears a foreign language the more words she'll pick up, and the meaning will start to come across before she becomes a fluent speaker. You can show this by having her understand only a few words at first: "Stephanie… airlock… come!" It's not that someone is speaking to her in a pigeon language, it's that she is only picking up familiar words.

Characters in a bilingual environment will share words from both languages mid-sentence, and fluent speakers will be comfortable speaking in both languages, so consider it a skillset among your characters rather than a realworld detail you need to show the audience.

Comment: I think you want "pidgin language", not "pigeon language".  But if anyone here _does_ speak pigeon language, I would love for them to teach me

Answer (score 2):

Not likely. Languages don't work like that, over long periods of time, and especially not when they evolve naturally.

Look at how language evolved in our world. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language) or the entire [subsection of scholarly research](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=evolution%20of%20language&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf4sWDxbLZAhXKtVMKHQZYDfAQgQMILTAA) into it. Boiled down to basics, before there was language, there were proto-languages. These proto-languages got more and more complex as our need for new words to describe new things expanded (that's not just a source of meat, that's a bear, and it can kill you if you're not careful!) The thing is, they sprung up in different places, and spread with those groups. That's why tonal languages (some African languages, Chinese) are so different. Why Slavic languages (Russian, for example) are so different. Why sentence structure in Japanese is different from English, let alone what you can omit in a sentence and still have it make perfect sense.

Now, that isn't to say there won't be a commonly agreed upon language of trade. But that gets tricky, because of the vast majority of languages on offer. Today the languages of engineering and commerce are (and please feel free to add any one you feel I've omitted):

- German
- Chinese
- Spanish
- English

And it gets even more complex if you get into certain fields. In IT (programming especially) the main language (of the west) is English. In medicine it's Latin. So there still isn't a universally agreed upon language.

Comment: By extension, you'll have sub-languages within each "race" already, based on caste/job/education/geography.... 2 engineers might get along famously, while 2 poets would be at each other's throats.

Comment: Most of your second paragraph is dubious. Nobody really knows how language started. There is no consensus on whether human language evolved from a single common ancestor or developed independently in different places. (Also, "proto-language" refers to the reconstructed common ancestor of a group of languages, not to something less than a language; Proto-Indo-European was just as full a language as English or Hindi.) The reason for differences among languages can be summed up very briefly: Languages evolve. That's all you really need to say.

Comment: @DLosc Did I gloss over a lot of the facts? Yes. Is it possible all languages come from a common source? Yes. Do we definitively know the nitty-gritty details of early language(s) (AKA proto-language)? No. But I do give a summary of the best guesses we have as I understand them.

However, those languages were not as full as current language. They couldn't be. Because in their current form, modern language has thousands of words for things they had no idea about back then. Examples: bacteria, technology, science, the twerk. Language change because new things happen, and they need a word.

Answer (score 2):

You write in a point of view - and while it's a movie, *The 13th Warrior* uses this very effectively. If it's a language the protagonist doesn't understand - says so "They were speaking in an odd melodic language" - If he recognises it, mention that.

Language barriers make good plot movers anyway. Finding a natural way to communicate - or even learning the language. While the babelfish or "common"/lingua franca trope is an option, it really sounds like you need to integrate the lack of mutual intelligibility into the fabric of your story.

Answer (score 1):

People might learn a simple constructed language when they are older which has  a fixed set of rules. (Old enough, that it isn't a native language.) Together with rigid rules this should prevent the language drifting.

This works similar to a lingua franca but you can justify more people knowing it because the language can be easier to learn than natural languages. You still have native languages and the locals can discuss secrets which your protagonists can't understand.

As an Example, the constructed language Esperanto has "la Fundamento" which enshrines its grammar and basic vocabulary. La Fundamento is 113 Years old now and (apart from some disagreement on gender neutral pronouns) still applies to modern day Esperanto. Details around it evolve, but the core remains stable. This is despite people marrying inside the Esperanto community and raising "Denaskuloj" which learn Esperanto as a first language.

Of course this brings its own set of problems: Why that language and why a constructed one. Its not like Esperanto is that successful in our World. But if you like this option, the folks in the Worldbuilding stackexchange would surely love to help you with ideas.

Comment: [Red Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf) had Esperanto as a future lingua franca, albeit mostly included as a joke for the character Rimmer to struggle with.

Answer (score 1):

When I wrote a Sci-Fi novel a couple of years ago (humans visiting a planet with human-lookalikes and a civilization like ours), I solved this problem by letting the crew get a 'Language transplant', a direct modification of the language-center of their brains.

The language itself was recorded from human satellites orbiting the planet, and translated and understood by an AI. Then all words and phrases was modified in the brain, and the crew would now talk and understand this language, but no longer their own.

This should be changed back to their original language when they returned.
Obviously, they could not read and write this new language, but that didn't matter.

I made this up out of laziness, because I just wanted to come around the language-problem in a fast way. It did not have anything else to do in the story.

Unfortunately the language-issue did play an important role later in the story, which made the process shine a little to the eyes, but I thought 'Hey, this *is* Sci-Fi, isn't it?'

Answer (score 1):

Think Chinese. China is huge, and many languages are spoken. People from one side of the country cannot converse with people from the other. However they all read the same characters, so they all read the same newspaper, and communicate in writing.

(I find this mind-boggling.)

Also, if you are in the Far East you can observe this kind of conversation before a meeting starts: In English; "which language do we use?" followed by some discussion until they find a common language, then they switch to that one (or stay with English).

Comment: That works with the Chinese languages because they all have very similar grammars, and are closely related, so using a logographic system works fine. Because their grammars are virtually identical, and mostly the only difference is pronunciation, if you draw symbols for words that don't reflect their pronunciation at all, it'll be readable to everyone. Of course, this wouldn't work with languages whose grammars vary, or worse yet aren't related to each other.